# Comparison of two class instances not having members as unique identifiers

Tags: c++, hash, comparison, comparator, comparison-operators

Consider two classes, `Node` and `Edge`, representing the nodes and the edges of a multigraph, respectively (see my MWE code below). My intention is to to use three `unordered_map`s:

(a) from `Node` variables to `Edge` data,

(b) from `Edge` variables to `Node` data, and

(c) from `Node` pairs to `double` variables.

I tried to write `bool operator==()` functions for `Node*` and `Edge*` and hash functions for `Node*`, `Edge*`, and `pair<Node*,Node*>`.

My first problem is related to the `bool operator==()` function of `Edge`. Although the labels of the `Node`s are certainly unique, this `bool operator==()` function is not correct for multiple edges having the same `start`s and `end`s (). Is there any chance to construct correct `bool operator==()` function using, *e.g.*, the memory address of the `Edge`s?

The second question is whether these functions result in saving only the different `Node/Edge/pair<Node,Node>` objects if only simple edges are assumed.

So, my MWE is as follows:

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std;


class Node
{
   public:
      Node(){};
      string label;
      bool operator==(const Node* other) const
      {return label == other->label;};
};

class Edge
{
   public:
      Edge(){};
      Node *start, *end;
      double weight;
      bool operator==(const Edge* other) const
      {return start->label == other->start->label && 
       end->label == other->end->label;};
      //{return this == *other;}
};

namespace std
{
   template <>
   struct hash<Node*>
   {
      size_t operator()(const Node* node) const
      {return hash<string>()(node->label);}
   };

   template <>
   struct hash<Edge*>
   {
      size_t operator()(const Edge* edge) const
      {
         auto hash1 = hash<Node*>()(edge->start);
         auto hash2 = hash<Node*>()(edge->end);
         return hash1 ^ hash2; 
      }
   };

   template <>
   struct hash<pair<Node*,Node*>>
   {
      size_t operator()(const pair<Node*, Node*>& p) const
      { 
          auto hash1 = hash<Node*>()(p.first); 
          auto hash2 = hash<Node*>()(p.second);
          return hash1 ^ hash2; 
      } 
   };
}; 

int main()
{
   Edge* edge;
   Node* node;

   unordered_map<Node*,Edge> n2e;
   unordered_map<Edge*,Node> e2n;
   unordered_map<pair<Node*,Node*>,double> np2w;

   edge = new Edge();
   edge->weight = 1.0;
   edge->start = new Node();
   edge->start->label = "A";
   edge->end = new Node();
   edge->end->label = "B";

   n2e[edge->start] = *edge;
   e2n[edge] = *(edge->start);
   np2w[make_pair(edge->start, edge->end)] = edge->weight;

   edge = &n2e[edge->start];
   node = &e2n[edge];

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The second question is ..." - *One* question per question, please.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: As for your problems with comparison, the compiler should tell you what it tried to do in the error messages. The messages should contain the exact types of the arguments it uses when invoking `operator==`. From that information it should not be hard to create the overloaded operator needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mostly define `operator==(const Edge&, const Edge*)`,
whereas you would need `operator==(const Edge*, const Edge*)`, but the latter cannot be defined.

You have to write class which define `operator()(const Edge*, const Edge*) const` and provide it in `std::unordered_map`.

```
struct MyEdgeComp
{
    bool operator()(const Edge* lhs, const Edge* rhs) const {
        return *lhs == *rhs; // Assuming you implement it
    }
};

std::unordered_map<Edge*, Node, std::hash<Edge*>, MyEdgeComp> e2n;
```